# What is the latest version of "sp-pnp-js" that is compatible with SPFx v1.4.1 (On-Premise)

Tags: 2019, sharepoint-framework, pnpjs

Does anyone know which is the latest version of sp-pnp-js that is compatible with SharePoint Framework v1.4.1 for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise?

Тhanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PnP JS V2 is supported version for SharePoint 2019 On-Premise.

Refer the bellows article for more details.

- [SPFx Compatibility matrix](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2019/12/30/spfx-compatibility-matrix/)
- [SPFx on premises](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v2/SPFx-on-premises/)
- [Issues for on premises](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1965)